# Trigger Lambda in different aws region from Kinesis Data Stream Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a Kinesis data Stream, which is ingesting data through through KPL.

My requirement is to consume stream data via Lambda in different region.

In Same region I acheived it via Kinesis Event.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-region Kinesis triggers are not supported by AWS Lambda at this time. A potential workaround is to consume Kinesis data with an intermediate Lambda in the same region and send them to the Lambda function on the other region.

Kinesis (region A) --> Lambda (region A) -->  (region B)

I should note this will result in extra Lambda invocation cost, time overload, and other considerations.